yarn global add windows-build-tools, GET https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/python/2.7.15/python-2.7.15.amd64.msi returned 404
PS C:\Users\member2> yarn global add windows-build-tools
yarn global v1.22.22
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning windows-build-tools@5.2.2: Node.js now includes build tools for Windows. You probably no longer need this tool. See https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools for details.
warning windows-build-tools > nugget > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning windows-build-tools > nugget > request > har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
warning windows-build-tools > nugget > request > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning windows-build-tools > nugget > progress-stream > through2 > xtend > object-keys@0.4.0:
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "electron-builder > app-builder-lib@24.13.3" has unmet peer dependency "electron-builder-squirrel-windows@24.13.3".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[1/2] ⢀ electron
error C:\Users\member2\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\windows-build-tools: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node ./dist/index.js
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\member2\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\windows-build-tools
Output:
Downloading python-2.7.15.amd64.msi
Error: GET https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/python/2.7.15/python-2.7.15.amd64.msi returned 404
Downloading Python failed. Error: Error: Could not find python-2.7.15.amd64.msi at https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/python/2.7.15/python-2.7.15.amd64.msi
at nuggetCallback (C:\Users\member2\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\download.js:60:35)
at done (C:\Users\member2\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\nugget\index.js:58:9)
at Request. (C:\Users\member2\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\nugget\index.js:197:58)
at Request.emit (node:events:519:28)
at Request.onRequestResponse (C:\Users\member2\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\request\request.js:1059:10)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:519:28)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (node:_http_client:698:27)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)
at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:540:22)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:519:28)
windows-build-tools will now exit.
yarn global add windows-build-tools,How to succeed?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
